# javascript: Display prompt text in h1 in created div

Tags: javascript, css

I have created simple javascript program. When I click on div tag it opens prompt dialog accept text from user, create div and display text above created div. Now my problem is I want to display prompt text in h1. I used this method to display text in h1 "newDiv.style = "h1";" But that doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this ?

code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("div1");
  x.onclick = function() {
    var mvytext = prompt("Enter text");

    var parent = mvytext.parentNode;
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.id = "myNewDiv";
    newDiv.className = "cdiv1";
    newDiv.style = "h1";


    var txt = document.createTextNode(mvytext);
    newDiv.appendChild(txt);

    var beforeMe = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, beforeMe);

  }
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.cdiv1 {
  background-color: #bdefb8;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%;height: 100px;padding: 10px;margin: 10px 0" id="div1">
  <h1>Click me to add a new movie. </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to display the text once it is added to the dom... H1 is another type of element, so you may need to create both the div and the H1

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = "myNewDiv";
newDiv.className = "cdiv1"; 

var txt =  document.createElement("h1"); // this will create the title
txt.innerHTML = mvytext;
newDiv.appendChild(txt);
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I also have one more doubt...after prompt I want to get parentNode. so, I used this "var parent = mvytext.parentNode;". but in console it does't refer..

Comment: @PoojaPatel myText is the string of text that the user entered into the prompt. It’s not an element and therefore doesn’t have a parent mode.

Comment: @ScottMarcus then Can I say I am getting parent by "var parent = mvytext.parentNode;" ?

Comment: sorry I mean to say "var parent = newDiv.parentNode;"

Comment: @PoojaPatel Yes, parentNode can be used on any node.

Answer (score 1):

`h1` isn't a style, it's an HTML tag - if your want to create an h1 element, that's not a DIV. If however you want to insert an `h1` element *into* the new div, you shouldn't define it as a style, but as the HTML contents of that div.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new h1 element with document.createElement(“h1”) instead of creating a div.

Comment: but I want to display prompt text in div.